# How to integrate a file upload into Spring Data REST repositories?

Tags: java, spring, http, file-upload, spring-data-rest

I would like to integrate a file upload and download into a Spring Data REST repository.

I have a `DataFile` class (see the implementation below) which is always accompanied by some metadata. There is a `DataFileRepository` to store information about the relation between the metadata and the file.

A user should be able to upload a file in a web-app form together with the metadata. The metadata should be stored in the database tables while the file is uploaded to some file storage, the path to the file is then stored in the entity again.

I would like to do this using Spring Data REST. My approach was to include a `MultipartFile` in the `DataFile` entity and mark it `@Transient` and `@RestResource(exported = false)` so it is not in any representation of the entity but can be uploaded.
When uploaded an `AbstractRepositoryEventListener` overrides `onBeforeCreate` and uploads the file during this step.

But with that approach I'm struggling to include the file in the HTTP requests body (a JSON representation of the `DataFile`).

Other approaches would include implementing a `@RestRepositoryController` to augment the `DataFileRepository` but the before mentioned approach would be my favorite.

What is the best practice to do a file upload using Spring Data REST (repositories)?

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "data_files")
public class DataFile {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private long identifier;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "path")
    @RestResource(exported = false)
    private String path;

    @Embedded
    private Metadata metadata;

    public DataFile() {
        metadata = new Metadata();
    }

    public DataFile(Metadata metadata) {
        this.metadata = metadata;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the exact same problem, did you find a solution?

Comment: Not one that purely uses Spring Data REST, but in conjunction with aspects it works fine and is a solution that integrates nicely with REST. I'll add an answer, maybe someone else comes up with a better answer.

Comment: I just asked a new question for a similar thing, if you can add answer here or there (either one) that would be great!! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59585693/how-do-you-save-files-for-entity-in-spring-data-rest

Comment: See below for my implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find a way to do this by only using Spring Data REST, but this solution integrates nicely into the repositories and requires not too much handwritten code.

Below is an example of such a solution for a different project than the one of the question, but you should get the idea.

Basically create a `@BasePathAwareController` so it adapts to the base path that you might have set for Spring Data REST. Then create mappings inside the controller with the appropriate paths. In this case there is a `@PostMapping` with a path to the `tutors` repository and a subpath for the related attachment that is uploaded here.

You can do validation either in this method or introduce an aspect on the save method of the repository.

In this case I have used an aspect to apply the processing to every call of the `save()` method of the repository.

```
@BasePathAwareController
@ExposesResourceFor(Tutor.class)
public class TutorRepositoryController {
    private AttachmentAssembler attachmentAssembler;

    private AttachmentRepository attachmentRepository;

    private TutorRepository tutorRepository;

    private RepositoryEntityLinks entityLinks;

    @Autowired
    public TutorRepositoryController(AttachmentAssembler attachmentAssembler,
                                     AttachmentRepository attachmentRepository,
                                     TutorRepository tutorRepository,
                                     RepositoryEntityLinks entityLinks) {
        this.attachmentAssembler  = attachmentAssembler;
        this.attachmentRepository = attachmentRepository;
        this.tutorRepository      = tutorRepository;
        this.entityLinks          = entityLinks;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/tutors/{id}/attachments/{name}")
    public ResponseEntity<EntityModel<Attachment>> saveAttachment(@RequestParam("data") MultipartFile file,
                                                                  @PathVariable long id,
                                                                  @PathVariable String name) {
        Tutor thisTutor = tutorRepository.findById(id);
        File tempFile;
        try {
            tempFile = File.createTempFile(FilenameUtils.getBaseName(file.getOriginalFilename()),
                                           FilenameUtils.getExtension(file.getOriginalFilename()));

            StreamUtils.copy(file.getResource().getInputStream(), new FileOutputStream(tempFile));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not create temporary file of uploaded file.");
        }

        Attachment saved =
                    attachmentRepository.save(new Attachment(name, thisTutor, tempFile, file.getOriginalFilename()));

        return ResponseEntity.created(entityLinks.linkForItemResource(Attachment.class, saved.getIdentifier())
                                                  .toUri()).body(attachmentAssembler.toModel(saved));
    }
}
```

This is the code of the aspect that handles file upload.

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class TutorRepositoryAspect {
    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TutorRepositoryAspect.class.getName());

    private AttachmentRepository attachmentRepository;

    private ApplicationConfiguration configuration;

    private S3Service s3Service;

    @Autowired
    public TutorRepositoryAspect(AttachmentRepository attachmentRepository,
                                 ApplicationConfiguration configuration,
                                 S3Service s3Service) {
        this.attachmentRepository = attachmentRepository;
        this.configuration        = configuration;
        this.s3Service            = s3Service;
    }

    @Pointcut(value = "execution(* com.example.tutor.backend.repository.attachment.AttachmentRepository.save(..)) && args(attachment)")
    private void repositorySave(Attachment attachment) {
    }

    @Before(value = "repositorySave(attachment)", argNames = "attachment")
    private Attachment beforeSave(Attachment attachment) {
        log.info("Received request to add attachment to tutor \"{}\".", attachment.getIdentifier());

        File file = attachment.getFile();

        // Validation

        String filePath = attachment.getAttachedTo().getIdentifier() + "-" + attachment.getName() + "-"
                          + attachment.getOriginalFileName();

        if (s3Service.isFilePresent(filePath)) {
            log.error("Could not upload file as there is a file already with the same name.");
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("File is already present.");
        }

        String s3Path = s3Service.uploadFile(file, filePath);

        attachment.setFilePath(s3Path);

        // This attachment is now being saved to database.
        return attachment;
    }
}
```

Comment: In your answer, the file gets put into Attachment and then the repository saves it. Where does it actually go? Does SDR handles that? Does it get written in the database just like the other properties of Attachment?

Comment: The file is passed on to the attachment object. It is then uploaded to a service in an Aspect. This might also be done in the controller if you like. I chose to do it in the Aspect to do this before any creation of an attachment. Would you like me to add this to the answer?

Comment: yes please that would be helpful thanks, because I cant figure out how to retain the relationship of a saved file with the Entity itself. Do you get some sort of file handle from your service and then you save that handle in your Attachment entity?

Comment: Added my aspect code. It is basically as follows: The user clicks upload, then the `@PostMapping` of the `BasePathAwareController` is called, the `MultipartFile` is then stored to a temporary file on the disk - the `File` is added to the `Attachment` object. Then the repository save function is called. This method has been augmented with the aspect which takes this temporary file, uploads it to the AWS S3 Service and saves the path in the S3 bucket to the `Attachment` object. After the aspect, the normal repository code is called (saving to database and so on).